# BadImageFormatException or System.DllNotFoundException When trying to run a c# project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, leptonica

I have built a cpp dll with output configuration manager settings as shown in the snapshot

[image: snapshot].

It builds successfully and dll gets created.Then to consume it I have written a c# project that includes the dll as follows

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport(@"somePath\ImgProcessorTrial.dll", EntryPoint = "ImgProc")]
```

After that I built it with the configuration as shown in the figure

[image: consumer_configuration]

When i try to run this application I get the following output in the console.

```
BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

After that When I change the build configurations and try to build it again the cpp project does not build and gives a lot of errors of the type as given below.

```
unresolved external symbol for all functions of leptonica library
```

This particular library leptonica and all the necessary ones are built individually on a 64 bit machine.When I try to change the configurations of the c# project I get the exception

```
DLLNotFoundException
```

What I do in the project is invoke the dll functions to read an image and manipulate it.I thought it was related to the format of the image i am trying to read.So I tried to Run the application with a .jpeg and .tif but with the same output always.I am doing all of this on a visual studio 2013 and framework 3.5 on a 64 bit machine.What is the exact meaning of the BadImageFormatException and how to solve it?Is it a code issue or architecture issue?

Comment: try to set plateforme as x86 or x64 instaed of any CPU

Comment: setting to x64 gives the dllNotFoundException and setting to to x86 has the same result of badImageFormatException

Comment: so keep x64 settings. where is your dll ? try inside bin folder of the c# project .

Comment: Please provide an answer if you have an absolute idea of what the issue is

Comment: Standard mistake, the Platform name in that dialog is meaningless for .NET programs.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab.  Set the Platform target there, you need to tick the "Prefer 32-bit" option so it is compatible with your 32-bit C++ DLLs.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not able to enable prefer 32-bit option as is it uneditable.

Comment: You are targeting an old .NET version, use x86 then.

Comment: @HansPassant My target when x86 gives the same error and with ANY CPU also gives the same error.Will remaking the project in a higher .net version help.Currently i was using 3.5.If yes do you know how to change it from 3.5 to 4 or higher without remaking if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

BadImageFormat is not related to .jpeg or .tif...

[BadImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This exception is thrown when the file format of a dynamic link
>   library (.dll file) or an executable (.exe file) does not conform to
>   the format that is expected by the common language runtime.

In your case you're calling a DLL that is itself 64 bit so you have to compile your project  to x64. You get the BadImageFormat when targeting x86